# PHP or cakephp: Why is += an unsupported operand

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I use:

**PHP** Version **5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5**

**CakePHP** version **2_3_6**

Installed BoostCake 1.0.6 the Bootstrap plugin for cakephp

I downloaded bootstrap 3.3.1 and putted the css and js files to the fodlers webroot/css and webroot/js

After setting up everything like described on [Boostcake](http://slywalker.github.io/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake/) I get this weird error:

> Error: Unsupported operand types File:
>
> /var/www/cakephp_2_3_6/app/Plugin/BoostCake/View/Helper/BoostCakePaginatorHelper.php
> Line: 102

**Line 102:**

```
    $options += $default;
```

$option and $default are arrays

Is this a function of php or of cakephp? Is the version to low I have?

**Edit**
As mentioned in the answers, the Problem was not PHP nor cakePHP. It was the (wrong) way I used the plugin which lead to an operation that tried to add together an array and null.

Comment: It's not php nor cakephp. It's because of the plugin. For some reason, the function is called with a parameter that is not an array. `$default` is array, so `$options` is probably not. Can you var_dump($options) before that line?

Comment: Thanks! It is the plugin. I didn't expect this. $options is null. I still don't know why, but I will find out. For now I just check that $options is not null ($default is hard coded).

Comment: All I can think about is make sure you use the plugin like in their examples.

Comment: Just throw an exception in the method and check the stacktrace to figure from where it is being invoked and what values are passed.

Answer (score 2):

The two variables are not compatible with each other. I'm assuming that one of the two (perhaps `$options`) is an array, and the other (maybe `$default`) is a numeric value, null, or a string.

So if default is a number, my assumption would be you're actually trying to do this:

```
$options[] = $default;
```

Or perhaps you expect them to be arrays anyway, and something is going wrong with creating `$options` or `$default`.

So if either `$default` or `$option` is based on a value that *you* have control over, you are likely passing the wrong values, because they *can't* be both arrays for that error to appear.

If you don't have control over the origin of these values, I think the most practical step forward is to actually just report it as a bug. If you followed their tutorial by the letter, I think it's safe to assume that there's a problem in their project, and it would be a bit much to ask stackoverflow to find and fix a bug.

Comment: instead of appending you could also just cast to an array. If the value is not an array/object, it will wrap it in one. Then the union operator would work.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn it's true that it will work, but it will always overwrite the first element in a numeric array. Somehow I feel that that's like not what OP is looking for, but I could be wrong. Just guessing here :)

Comment: Actually it won't when using the union operator. Values in the left array are *not* overwritten by values in the right array, only values that don't exist in the left array are added. This is exactly opposite of `array_merge($options, $default)`. If key `0` already exists in the `$options` array, it will just use the value from `$options[0]`, not overwrite it with `$default[0]`. Also, with `array_merge`, numeric keys are appended, not overwritten either. So really it should likely be `array_merge($default, (array)$options)`. Numeric keys will be appended and assoc in $options will overwrite.

Comment: Both of you might want to have a look at the linked source code, neither does the OP want to append something to an array, nor is the `$default` variable the problem. It's a 3rd party plugin, and the code wants to unionize two arrays, where `$default` is hard-coded, so obviously `$options` must be the problem (for whatever reason).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: right, but it will still be a stretch to assume that that's actually the desired behavior ;). ndm, fair enough...  I'll append my answer with your comment.

Comment: I still don't understand how this can happen. After all it is one of those "just load the plugin and everything will be fine, no much need for explanations or documentation!" plugins. I didn't expect the plugin to be the problem. But ndm is right. I now check with an if else statement whether or not **$option** is set. If not I set **$options = $default**. That solves at least this problem I have with that plugin :)